# How can I access Exchange Server 2007 public folders using Outlook 2013?

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook

I have a client that just purchased office 2013, and they have Exchange 2007. I cannot find their public calendar or contacts anywhere.

Where/how can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Public Folders for Exchange 2007 from Office 2013 do this:

1. Open Outlook 2013
2. Click on the three dots as shown in this picture
   [image]
3. Then click on Folders
4. From here you will be able to see (on the left hand pane) the Public Folders section.  Click on it to expand it.  If you need to add any company calendars or shared items from here back to people's Outlook, you can right click on them (a shared calendar for example) and select "Add To Favorites"

If I'm missing what you're asking for just let me know, but I'm sure this is it.